# W8-BEN form for Indian student pursuing PhD in USA (NJ)

Tags: college, research, form-w-8-ben

I got admitted to Rutgers as a PhD student and I'd be getting around $25.9k for my TA-ship each year. My department asked me to fill the W8-BEN form but I got stuck while filling fields 5 (SSN) , 7 (Reference Numbers) and 10 (Special Rates).

This is my first time in the US so I don't have an  SSN, I will apply for it once I reach there so what should I fill in field 5?

I have no clue about what 7 or 10 is, I tried reading the instructions but it seemed too technical for me. All I could understand was that, I must fill the field 10 as I fall under the category Researcher/Teacher, I tried reading the US - India tax treaty but it was of no help.